# $elemmatch returns only one result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having one document,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc864fe3cbb0d393687120b"),
    "eStatus" : "y",
    "aQuestions" : [
        {
            "eStatus" : "y",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bcd7818f0903a1c82aeef85"),
            "sQuestion" : "aabbccdd?",
        },
        {
            "eStatus" : "n",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bcda6aac272142b96ba77c3"),
            "sQuestion" : "sdfdsf",
        },
        {
            "eStatus" : "y",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bcda6bfc272142b96ba77c6"),
            "sQuestion" : "vnmhjk",
        },
        {
            "eStatus" : "n",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bd69f7516972c11234a3613"),
            "sQuestion" : "What is use of Wallet in ParadiseXtrade ?",

        }
    ],
}
```

My Query: `helpFaqsModel.findOne({_id: req.body._id,aQuestions: {$elemMatch: {eStatus: "y"}}})`

I am not sure what is the correct way to find the list of questions which has `eStatus: "y"`

I want to find the first document from the collection and from that collection which has `eStatus:"y"`

Comment: Use $filter as noted in the duplicate.

Comment: @Veeram I dont think that is the correct duplicate.  OP doesn't want to filter elements, just wants to find the first document match.  Would be helpful if if you post your response from the query you are trying and the results you wish to receive

Comment: honestly i think that you want to use `helpFaqsModel.findOne({"eStatus":"y"})`